# Moving code to Opencv cv::ParallelLoopBody

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this opencv function:

```
static std::vector<cv::Point> findBoundaryPixels(const cv::Mat_<uchar> &trimap, int a, int b)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> result;
    for (int x = 1; x < trimap.cols - 1; ++x)
        for (int y = 1; y < trimap.rows - 1; ++y)
        {
            if (trimap(y, x) == a)
            {
                if (trimap(y - 1, x) == b ||
                    trimap(y + 1, x) == b ||
                    trimap(y, x - 1) == b ||
                    trimap(y, x + 1) == b)
                {
                    result.push_back(cv::Point(x, y));
                }
            }
        }


    return result;
}
```

i am looking into speeding my application up using the opencv `ParallelLoopBody` code, to run every-pixel operations in parallel.

I have added this class:

```
class Parallel_process : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{

private:
    cv::Mat trimap;
    int a;
    int b;
    std::vector<cv::Point>& result;

public:
    Parallel_process(cv::Mat inputImgage, std::vector<cv::Point>& presult, int aa, int bb)
        : trimap(inputImgage), result(presult), a(aa), b(bb) {}

    virtual void operator()(const cv::Range& range) const
    {
        for (int i = range.start; i < range.end; i++)
        {

            int x = i / trimap.cols;
            int y = i / trimap.rows;

            if (trimap.at<uchar>(y, x) == a)
            {
                if (trimap.at<uchar>(y - 1, x) == b ||
                    trimap.at<uchar>(y + 1, x) == b ||
                    trimap.at<uchar>(y, x - 1) == b ||
                    trimap.at<uchar>(y, x + 1) == b)
                {
                    result.push_back(cv::Point(x, y));
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

and adjusted the function so that it reads:

```
static std::vector<cv::Point> findBoundaryPixels(const cv::Mat_<uchar> &trimap, int a, int b)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> result;
    // create 8 threads and use TBB
    cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, 8), Parallel_process(trimap, result, a, b));

    return result;
}
```

However, this crashes my application. I have tried to follow the docs, as here:

https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html

But have clearly failed. Where am i going wrong with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tutorial input `cv::Range` for `cv::parallel_for_` is `[0, img.cols * img.width]`, you should do it in the same way. This input range is splitted into smaller ranges and they are passed as parameters of operator() which is executed by thread.

So you should call

```
cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, trimap.cols * trimap.rows), Parallel_process(trimap, result, a, b));
```

In `void operator()(const cv::Range& range)` you should use value of `range` to calculate `x` and `y`. When your image has WIDTH and HEIGHT, and we know that pixels are stored in rows, you can use these formulas

> x = r % WIDTH     (r value of range)
>
> y = r / WIDTH

next you should add conditions to check if pixel is on borders (x == 0, y == 0, etc)

```
    int x = i % trimap.cols;
    int y = i / trimap.cols;
    
     if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == trimap.cols-1 || y == trimap.rows-1)
          continue;

     if (trimap.at<uchar>(y, x) == a)
     {
         if (trimap.at<uchar>(y - 1, x) == b ||
             trimap.at<uchar>(y + 1, x) == b ||
             trimap.at<uchar>(y, x - 1) == b ||
             trimap.at<uchar>(y, x + 1) == b)
            {
                // ---> result.push_back(cv::Point(x, y));
            }
     }
```

and the most important thing you call `push_back` on vector without synchronizing. You should use `mutex` to lock access to vector. If you are using C++11 you can define mutex in your `operator()` as static variable

```
static cv::Mutex mtx;
mtx.lock();
result.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
mtx.unlock();
```

when you are using older version than C++11, you can keep reference to mutex (must be created before calling `cv::parallel_for_`) in `Parallel_process` and call lock/unlock on it.

In tutorial synchronization is not needed because output cv::Mat was created and for each value of range different pixel (x,y) is written.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I have one question, `x = r % WIDTH`, is the `i` in this case what i should use for `r`? And width would be `trimap.cols`, correct?

Comment: Yes, `width` is `trimap.cols` and `i` means value of range - your index in for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. A perfect answer. :)